# OpenCV: What to use? Cascade Classifier or Feature Detector (SURF, ORB,...)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV. I read a lot and I did the tutorials. So far, so good. But for my own project I am now on the point where I have to choose a algorithm for realtime feature detection and I am not quit sure which is the best for my needs.

I want to detect a certain shape in an image. If this shape changes over a certain amount, I don't want to detect it or detect it as different.

Let's say we have the profile of a persons head. I now just focus on the top of his head:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3525/unnub6a3_png.htm

Now if the person wears a hat, I don't want to detect it any more. I just want to detect this shape in slight variations (slightly different angle, rotated, scaled, maybe even another person without a hat?). I want to set a threshold if it changes too much from the original.

No should I train cascade classifiers with only this feature or should I use something like SURF or ORB? Or is there even a better option?

I don't want to detect that it is a person or even recognise him/her. I just want to detect a shape in slightly different types.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think Haar-cascades are more suitable for this problem, though they're not very accurate from my experience.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that as well. Because of that I was looking for alternatives.
If the camera is fixed and has a defined background I could isolate the object by subtracting the background. I should get clear shapes then.
I am looking into template matching right now. Maybe I can get it a bit more flexible.
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html